# How to restart the NativeScript Angular app?

Tags: nativescript, restart, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

I'm looking for a solution that helps me, with performing a restart to the native app programmatically.

I'm using the android platform only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I've used
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
inside of setTimeout witch working in most cases...
and for iphone i used
exit(0) or exit();

my code is looks like this:

Comment: performRestart() {
        this.showIndicator();
        if (isAndroid) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                // android.foregroundActivity.finish();
                this.hideIndicator();
            }, 5000);
        } else {
            setTimeout(() => {
                exit(0);
                this.hideIndicator();
            }, 5000);
        }
    }